# Override change_form.html in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-admin

I have built a Content Management System where I am able to upload photos, single photo at a time. Now I need to allow multiple photo upload option simultaneously. For doing that, I'm following this blog post https://blog.rousek.name/2017/08/11/uploading-multiple-files-in-django-admin/.

It tells that there should be an admin directory inside templates inside my_app inside my_project. Many other resources on googling also suggested the same thing. Inside that admin directory is where I'll find the models and there change_form.html which I need to override.

But I'm not able to find the admin directory itself. This is my project directories tree.

```
   .
├── cms
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── images
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   └── js
├── templates
│   └── cms
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── register.html
│       ├── upload-pdf.html
│       ├── upload-photo.html
│       └── view-all.html
└── zoomtail
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

templates/my_app contains all the HTML files that I created. I have followed the flow as suggested in tangowithdjango book.

Is this have to do with how I built my project directory or is the change_form.html hidden somewhere?

Comment: Minimize your file tree to make your question readable.

Comment: Okay, I have minimized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override admin template. Based on your Django version, the way it's done can slightly differ. Admin templates reside under `contrib/admin/templates/admin` directory of your Django installation in case if you are interested in viewing them. Refer to related part here: [for Django v2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

Comment: So I need to take change_form.html from contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html and paste it in cms/templates/admin/cms/images/ with appropriate additions?

Comment: Would be more helpful if you also tell the procedure/code instead of a link.